# How do you install Drush 7 for Drupal 8? Installed composer and still doesnt work.

Tags: drush, installation

I'm trying to install drush 7 for drupal 8, but im hitting a snag. I installed composer and now i downloaded drush 7 and unzipped it to /opt/drush7

I get the follow error when running drush even after i installed composer:

```
$ ./drush

Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
./drush: line 124: [: too many arguments
Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer in order to install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md
```

I then run this from the read me file:

```
$ composer install
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.17
Content-type: text/html

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/local/bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Comment: `cd /path/to/drush` then try again..

Comment: What version of php are you using?  If you run `php -r 'print PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'` from the command line, what does it print?